# Exponents without Math.pow() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, math, exponentiation

I need to write a program that takes two integers base and exponents and compute the exponents without using Math.Pow(). I have created the code using the Math.pow() method I can't figure out how to make it work without it. I have tried base^exp but it doesn't give me the right answer. Thanks in advance!

/* Write a JavaScript function named intPow that reads two numbers named base and exp from two text fields. Assume that the second number will always be an integer greater than or equal to 1. Your function should not use any of the built in Math functions such as Math.pow. Your function should use a loop to compute the value of baseexp meaning base raised to the power of exp. Your function must output the result of baseexp to a div. Hint: write your function to compute 1 multiplied by base exp times. */

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Integer Power</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Write a JavaScript function named intPow that reads two numbers named base and exp from two text fields. Assume that the second number will always be an integer greater than or equal to 1. Your function should not use any of the built in Math functions such as Math.pow. Your function should use a loop to compute the value of baseexp meaning base raised to the power of exp. Your function must output the result of baseexp to a div. Hint: write your function to compute 1 multiplied by base exp times. */
    function intPow() {
        var base = parseFloat(document.getElementById("baseBox").value);
        var exp = parseFloat(document.getElementById("expBox").value);
        var output = "";
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= exp; i++) {
            output = Math.pow(base, exp);
        }
        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = output;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Find the power of <i>Base</i> by entering an integer in the <i>base</i> box, and an integer in the <i>exponent</i> box.</h1> Base:
<input type="text" id="baseBox" size="15"> Exponents:
<input type="text" id="expBox" size="15">
<button type="button" onclick="intPow()">Compute Exponents</button>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: Why `math.Pow()` does not suit?

Comment: Hint: `a ^ b = a * a * a ... (b times)`.

Comment: @simoco Because it is a homework task for learning loops.

Comment: But this is not the place for doing someone's homework

Comment: Im not asking for anyone to do my HW I am asking for guidance. I have done most of the code. I just don't understand how compute the exponents without math.pow()

Comment: Yeldar has already given you a hint in the right direction. You're looking for loops. Something like "multiply `a` by itself `b` times."

Comment: I was able to figure it out :
output = (1 * base ) * exp
Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking this up in the future, such as me just now, this is a solid solution:

```
function computePower(num, exponent) {
      var result = 1;
      for (i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
      result *= num;
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Given a number and an exponent, "computePower" returns the given number, raised to the given exponent.

@user5500799,

```
output = (1 * base ) * exp;
```

won't work, because you are not raising the base to the exponent, just multiplying it. Starting with a multiplication with 1 is great though: in my code, that ensures that, for example, 2 to the power of 0 is 1 (everything to the power of 0 is one, which is something that is defined)

Comment: Not solid enough, try `computePower(2, 0.5)` will give you wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

with ES2016 you can use the [exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)).

```
2 ** 8 // 256
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by changint output to:

output = (1 * base ) * exp;